# In C++ Is there a way for the Child to reuse the the Parent class implementation of the pure virtual function defined in GrandParent

Tags: c++, oop, events, c++11

Consider the below code, EventGeneratorBase is a helper class intended to provide the actual implementation for `AddEventHandler()` and I would like to use that implementation in the class `RemoteControl` instead of explicity defining it. I know it's not possible to instantiate `RemoteControl` without defining the method but is there a shortcut or an easy way to avoid manually defining the methods.

---

*Note: The code in it's present form doesn't compile because RemoteControl can't be instantiated.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<class TEventHandler> struct IEventGenerator {
    virtual ~IEventGenerator() = default;
    virtual void AddEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<TEventHandler> eventHandler) = 0;
};

template <class TEvents> struct EventGeneratorBase : IEventGenerator<TEvents> {
    void AddEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<TEvents> target) {
        _eventHandlers.push_back(target);
    }

    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<TEvents>> GetEventHandlers() {
        return _eventHandlers;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<TEvents>> _eventHandlers;
};


struct IControlEvents {
    virtual ~IControlEvents() = default;
    virtual void PowerOn() = 0;
    virtual void PowerOff() = 0;
};

struct IRemoteControl  : IEventGenerator<IControlEvents> {
    virtual ~IRemoteControl() = default;
    virtual void Toggle() = 0;
};

struct RemoteControl : IRemoteControl, EventGeneratorBase<IControlEvents> {
    // I don't want to define AddEventHandler() in this class and
    // would like to inherit the implementation from EventGeneratorBase

    void Toggle() {
        for (auto tref : GetEventHandlers()) {
            auto t = tref.lock();
            if (t) {
                t->PowerOn();
                t->PowerOff();
            }
        }
    }
};

struct Light : IControlEvents {
    Light(std::string color) : _color(color) { }

    void PowerOn() {
        std::cout << _color << "::Light ON!" << std::endl;
    }

    void PowerOff() {
        std::cout << _color << "::Light OFF!" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string _color;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<IRemoteControl> remote(new RemoteControl); // ERROR: Can't instantiate
    std::shared_ptr<IControlEvents> light1(new Light("GREEN"));
    std::shared_ptr<IControlEvents> light2(new Light("RED"));

    remote->AddEventHandler(light1);
    remote->AddEventHandler(light2);
    remote->Toggle();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please simplify the example?

Comment: `PowerOn` and `PowerOff` are in `IControlEvents` not `EventGeneratorBase`... I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Manually defining `AddEventHandler` where is the problem?  What does `// I need to use AddEventHandler() from EventGeneratorBase` mean?  Does the above code work, or not?   "I had like to use the base class method" looks like it contains grammar errors, it doesn't make sense.  What **exactly** do you mean by " manually defining the methods."  I see you have a listener/broadcaster system: the thing I dislike about your system is having to write `Toggle` more than anything.

Comment: @Barry Sorry that was a typo, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Side note: You should inherit interfaces virtually

Comment: @Yakk Eg: RemoteControl has two IEventGenerator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two distinct sub-objects of type `IEventGenerator<IControlEvents>` within your `RemoteControl` object.  One via `EventGeneratorBase<IControlEvents>` and one via `IRemoteControl`.

There are two ways to prevent you from having two distinct subobjects.  The first is to inherit `virtual`ly from `IEventGenerator<TEventHandler>` in both spots.  This has a modest run-time cost.  Simply add `virtual` before every case of inheritance from `IEventGenerator<?>` and you are done.

A second method is to note that `EventGeneratorBase` is intended to help with implementing `IEventGenerator`.

```
template<class T> struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag> using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<class TEventHandler>
tag<TEventHandler> get_event_handler_type(
  IEventGenerator<TEventHandler> const*
) { return {}; }
template<class X>
using event_handler_type = type_t< decltype( get_event_handler_type( (X*)nullptr ) ) >;

template <class Base, class TEvents = event_handler_type<Base>>
struct EventGeneratorHelper :
  Base
{
  void AddEventHandler(std::weak_ptr<TEvents> target) override {
    _eventHandlers.push_back(target);
  }

  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<TEvents>> GetEventHandlers() {
    return _eventHandlers;
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<TEvents>> _eventHandlers;
};
```

now, go down to here:

```
struct RemoteControl :
  EventGeneratorHelper<IRemoteControl>
{
```

and change how we inherit.  We now interpose `EventGeneratorHelper` between us and `IRemoteControl`, so they now share the same common `IEventGenerator`.

This removes the need for `virtual` inheritance, but does up your compile time, and can cause some executable code bloat.

We can go a step further.  Add this to `EventGeneratorHelper`:

```
template<class Action>
void FireEvents( Action&& action ) const {
  for (auto tref : GetEventHandlers()) {
    auto t = tref.lock();
    if (t) {
      action(t);
    }
  }
}
```

which reduces `RemoteControl` to:

```
struct RemoteControl :
  EventGeneratorHelper<IRemoteControl>
{
  void Toggle() {
    this->FireEvents([](std::shared_ptr<IRemoteControl> const& ptr){
      t->PowerOn();
      t->PowerOff();
    });
  }
};
```

which I think is nice -- requiring clients to know the right way of iterating seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your inheritance hierarchy.

```
template <class TEvents> struct EventGeneratorBase :IEventGenerator<TEvents> {
    [...]
};

struct IRemoteControl  : IEventGenerator<IControlEvents> { 
    [...]
};

struct RemoteControl : IRemoteControl, EventGeneratorBase<IControlEvents> {
    [...]
};
```

This is not doing what you might expect. Instead, your class `RemoteControl` inherits *twice* from `IEventGenerator`, once from `IRemoteControl` and once from `EventGeneratorBase`.